# Elixir package broken after installation

Tags: apt, package-management

I have installed the elixir package using `apt install elixir`, which reports no errors. However, when I run `elixir -v` I get the message `-bash: /usr/bin/elixir: No such file or directory`.

I have tried `apt purge elixir` and this completes successfully as well, but installing elixir after purging does not resolve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

The solution in the end was completely reinstall the server and run this process:

Add Erlang Solutions repo:

```
wget https://packages.erlang-solutions.com/erlang-solutions_1.0_all.deb && sudo dpkg -i erlang-solutions_1.0_all.deb
```

Run:

```
sudo apt-get update
```

Install the Erlang/OTP platform and all of its applications:

```
sudo apt-get install esl-erlang
```

Install Elixir:

```
sudo apt-get install elixir
```

As per the [Elixir](https://elixir-lang.org/install.html) installation page.

I would recommend anyone who may be reading this and attempt to install this package, to make sure to follow the official instructions on this page to the letter and not use third-party instructions or shortcuts as some alternative packages seem to partially over-write others, causing a broken installation which requires either in-depth knowledge (and a lot of time) or potentially drastic action to rectify.